# How can we pass variables from two functions to one function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Passing the variable X and y to the function C...
How to do it?

```
function a(){
    let x = 1;
}

function b(){
    let y = 2;
}

function c(){
    let z;
    z = x + y;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to return the value of x and y accordingly, your functions need to return the data and THEN store it inside a variable.

```
function a(){
    return 1; // MAKE SURE TO RETURN the data you need from your function A
}

function b(){
    return 2; // Return the data from your function B
}

function c(){
    let z,
        x = a(); // Returns 1 inside the X variable
        y = b(); // Returns 2 inside the Y variable
    z = x + y;  // z = 1 + 2
    return z    // 3
}

c() // 3
```

https://repl.it/@fernandob/passing-data-from-2-funds#index.js

Comment: function a(){
 let x = 1;
 let y = 2;
 }                                                                                                                               function b(){
    let z,   
    z = x + y;  
 }